# DI in directive results in unknown somethingProviderProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that AngularJS appends "Provider" to registered providers, so it is not necesary to name them with that "provider" and you should call them with the full name as "SomethingProvider".
I'm doing that but the console throws me an

Unknown provider: ReportProviderProvider <- ReportProvider <- reportDirective

I have a service, provider and directive called Report, everyone in its own file. ReportProvider.js, ReportService.js, ReportDirective.js

When I try to use the directive I got the error.
Why do angular appends "Provider" to my required dependency?

```
angular.module('thdmaterialApp')
  .provider('Report', function () {});

angular.module('thdmaterialApp')
  .service('Report', function (ReportProvider) {
});

angular.module('thdmaterialApp')
 .directive('report', function (ReportProvider) {} );
```

Comment: It is best if your question actually contains a question. I don't see one. There is an implicit question here, but it is better if you ask it explicitly.

Comment: thanks for editing -- I don't know the answer but now someone can look at your question and see exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to write it like this **ReportProvider** ,, you just need to inject **Report** ,,
you will have to add **Provider** when you want to use it in **config** ,, but in DI it works as other injectable services ,,
and I think of course you will need to change the name of Report service ,,

Comment: "you will have to add Provider when you want to use it in config ,, but in DI it works as other injectable services" This is what I was looking for. It is not documented or am I just dumb?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject a the provider into your directive? I think they are only meant to be used inside `config` blocks to pre-configure a service. From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers):

> You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API
>   for application-wide configuration that must be made before the
>   application starts. This is usually interesting only for reusable
>   services whose behavior might need to vary slightly between
>   applications.

Also, I think your provider will need to define `this.$get` as a function that returns an object for it to work.

You only need to use provider if you want to be able to change some properties on a service in some situations. I've tried to show this in a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EWfxg8V7fRHy2Z8Xlnyt?p=preview) you might find helpful.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('thdmaterialApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ReportService, Report) {
  $scope.serviceValue =  ReportService.value;
  $scope.value = Report.getValue();

});


app.provider('Report', function () {


  // if you remove the config block you should see this value
  this.value = 'default';

  this.configureValue = function(newValue){
    this.value = newValue;
  }

  this.$get = function() {

        var value = this.value;
        return {
            getValue: function() {
                return value
            }
        }
    };

});

// if you comment this out then the default value will be returned
app.config(function(ReportProvider){
  ReportProvider.configureValue('new configured value');
});

app.service('ReportService', function () {
  return {
    value: 'I don\'t need to be configured.'
  };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="thdmaterialApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>ReportService.value: {{serviceValue}}</p>
    <p>Report.getValue(): {{value}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know the differences. I have correctly implemented the code I just didn't paste the completed one. I'm injecting the provider since I need a value from an event declared in it (I know that I'll need to refactorize). Ahmed got it right saying that Angular does not append "provider" when it's gonna be used in config.